# REST endpoint to retrieve multiple images

Tags: rest, http, mime-types

My web application requires a REST endpoint `GET /products` whose semantics is to retrieve a set of products from a product catalogue.
Each product has a set of attributes including an image in PNG format:

```
[
    {
        productId: 123, 
        name: "boat", 
        image: "\\x89504e470d0a1a0..."   <-- PNG retrieved from PostgreSQL bytea 
    },
    {
        productId: 456, 
        name: "helicopter", 
        image: ...
    }
    ... and many more
]
```

I believe this approach is not REST compliant because the image's Mime-Type is not explicitly mentioned.
The approach that is closer to the REST spirit would be to include, instead of the binary data, a hyperlink to the image resource

```
[
    {
        productId: 123, 
        name: "boat", 
        image: { 
            href: "/product/123/image <-- GET response to this resource has Mime-Type image/png
        }
    },
    {
        productId: 456, 
        name: "helicopter", 
        image: { 
            href: "/product/123/image <-- GET response to this resource has Mime-Type image/png
        }
    }
    ... and many more
]
```

But in that case the client would need to `GET` the product images one-by-one which adds significant overhead to the network (TCP connections) and the database (querying for the images one-by-one).

Is there a best practice for embedding multiple images in a single json response with the correct Mime-Type?

Comment: The overhead of embedding images in JSON file is going to be _way_ worse than just using more HTTP requests. Browers re-use TCP connections with HTTP/1.1, and will only 1 use TCP connection for many requests with HTTP/2. This feels like a terrible idea.

Comment: Do you have a performance problem or do you think you might? Websites use images, it's OK :P

Comment: @Evert thank you for the hint with HTTP/2. I remember in the 2010s bundling assets was a must for performant web applications. With the advent of HTTP/2 the opposite seems to be the case (https://speedboostr.com/concatenation-case-study/). I don't have any performance issues yet, but I need to design a system that can serve 10 simultaneous users who download 100 product images (each ~ 100KB) in under 2 seconds over a 10mbps (=1.25 MB/sec) mobile network. Now if I stick to downloading the images one-by-one, the database may become a bottleneck. But +33% traffic due to base64 is not good either

Comment: I would strongly suggest you do things the 'right' way before thinking about optimization strategies that might squeeze a bit more speed out of this, in exchange for a much worse API. Measure, improve, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a best practice for embedding multiple images in a single json response with the correct Mime-Type?

It sounds like what you are looking for is [the "data" URL Scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2397) ([RFC 2397](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2397)), which allows you to specify the media type as part of the URL.

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAMAAwAAAC8IyPqcvt3wCcDkiLc7C0qwyGHhSWpjQu5yqmCYsapyuvUUlvONmOZtfzgFzByTB10QgxOR0TqBQejhRNzOfkVJ+5YiUqrXF5Y5lKh/DeuNcP5yLWGsEbtLiOSpa/TPg7JpJHxyendzWTBfX0cxOnKPjgBzi4diinWGdkF8kjdfnycQZXZeYGejmJlZeGl9i2icVqaNVailT6F5iJ90m6mvuTS4OK05M0vDk0Q4XUtwvKOzrcd3iq9uisF81M1OIcR7lEewwcLp7tuNNkM3uNna3F2JQFo97Vriy/Xl4/f1cf5VWzXyym7PHhhx4dbgYKAAA7
```